# Commit only partial changes in a set of files with git

Tags: git

I am using a tool that generates a bunch of .xml files. All of the files contain a specific block of text.

Eg:

```
<classAccesses>
    <class>TestClass</class>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

This text will exist in ~100 different files in this exact format, but:

- it will be at different line numbers in each file.
- The files will also contain other diff that I do not want to commit

So I need to commit only this block of text in all 100 files and no other changes. Is this possible?

Comment: Committing only a piece of generated files can be a nightmare to manage conflict that will appear.

Comment: @Ôrel I'm sure it can be, but right now its always a nightmare to manually commit this block of code 100 times

Comment: Hi, yes - first stash all current changes so that state of any files are same than current in git repository. After stash append your block to all necessary files. Mark that files to add for commit and commit. After that get stash back from stack. (stash push; change xmls; commit; stash pop)

Comment: @TomFreudenberg Thank you for the suggestion, I was hoping there would be some git utility that had this functionality, but It looks like this may be the route I have to take

Answer (score -1):

The immediate problem here is how to tell git what you want to stage, and what you don't.

You can use `git add -p` to stage parts of files.  You still have to identify the changes you want and the changes you don't.  You could try to automate that by piping through a script that looks for the text you want to add, then says 'y' at the next prompt, and says 'n' at all other prompts; but it may not be that simple if the code you want is adjacent to other changes.  So if it were me, I might just bite the bullet and run `git add -p` manually, figuring it's better than editing each file by hand.  If you only have to do it once, it may be better than beating your head against the wall trying to make a fully automated solution that in the end is still a one-off.

That said, this may be setting you up for future problems, as git won't just "forget" that those other changes exist.  If you can throw away the other changes locally (e.g. by doing a `git restore --staged` after the `git add -p`) then it's fine; but if you need the changes locally and just don't want them in the repo, then you might need to rethink your approach more generally, because in the long term tracking files "except for some local changes" is very much against the grain of how git works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't think Patch will work because, as you said, adjacent changes will force me to accept/reject the whole block. This is a frequent occurrence for me. I am able to discard all other diff in the file. And unfortunately this needs to be done on every feature branch, so it is a common task.

Comment: What that prevents is automation.  It is not true that you are required to accept/reject the whole block; you have options up to and including editing the patch by hand.  So it definitely will work, and is the closest thing git is going to have for what you want.  So if that can't be automated enough for your purposes, then you either are gong to have to write a tool to process the files yourself, or (as I noted before) may have to rethink why your'e doing things the way you are.

Comment: Hi @MarkAdelsberger, please checkout my answer - it isn't a problem to mark the files you want to commit. If you do understand "the force of git" (may the force be with you) it is very easy to work on different checkouts or sets of files and changes. Therefor you may use "git clone" more than once or use "git stash" or use "branches" or .... Best of all - if you granulary your changes in small and placed commits, it is most of the time also the cleanest way to merge them into other changes.

Answer (score -1):

In case of non currently working answer I post my workflow suggestion as answer because that is straight forward in git.

## OPTION 1: GIT STASH

You may postpone all current changes of your files in the git stash cache. After that the files are equal to former checkout state.

Lets say you have a repo "myrepo" and checked that out some day:

```
cd /home/me
git clone gihub.com/myrepo
cd myrepo
```

Then you made changes to that checked out files

```
vi file1.txt
vi file2.txt
```

After some time you need to apply some special changes to file1.txt and file3.txt.

You may do this workflow:

```
git stash push
vi file1.txt
vi file3.txt
git add .
git commit -m "super fast preferred changes"
git push
git stash pull
```

Now work on your last working changes.

## OPTION 2: SECOND CHECKOUT

Another option is to checkout the repo into a second path and make only other changes:

```
cd /home/me
git clone gihub.com/myrepo myrepo-2nd
cd myrepo-2nd
```

Now, you may do this workflow:

```
vi file1.txt
vi file3.txt
git add .
git commit -m "super fast preferred changes"
git push
```

After that you may remove the second checked out files and continue with you first checkout:

```
cd ..
rm -rf myrepo-2nd
cd myrepo
```

To get all changes from you preferred previous commit:

```
git pull
```

Now continue your work.

Comment: Not sure why someone had downvoted my answer and workflow suggestion - but - well. In any case I would be happy to get a comment when my answer is leading wrong.